Calendarpicker con encabezado desfazado
Estoy modificando un portal, existe un formulario que contiene un input para un Calendar picker, pero el encabezado que indica el dia de la semana no coincide con la fecha real, se utiliza la libreria Metro_UI, al crear el input en el HTML intente utilizar la propiedad data-week-start="1" para indicar que el dia inicial fuera el lunes, tambien intente utilizar data-locale="en-US", para utilizar la intercionalización, pero tampoco funcionó, ¿Que otra propiedad puedo utilizar para modificar este comportamiento?

Tomo como ejemplo el dia de hoy (22/08/2024), en el header del calendario indica que el 22 de agosto es viernes, cuando en la realidad en jueves.
Estoy definiendo el input de la siguiente manera:
<input type="text" data-prepend="Start Date:" data-validate="required" autocomplete="off" id="Date" name="Date" value="" data-role="calendarpicker" data-cls-calendar="compact" data-min-date="@DateTime.Now" data-format="%d/%m/%Y" data-input-format="%d/%m/%Y">

Ejemplo minimo verificable


<script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/current/metro.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/current/metro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-prepend="Start Date:" data-validate="required" autocomplete="off" id="Date" name="Date" value="" data-role="calendarpicker" data-cls-calendar="compact" data-format="%d/%m/%Y" data-input-format="%d/%m/%Y" data-show-header="false">




Hola Robinson, tu ejemplo mínimo verificable... a mi me funciona bien

Hola Robinson, al igual que Marcos, tu ejemplo mínimo verificable funciona correctamente. Saludos.
